# making two requests to the same controller in rails integrations specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm having problem making two requests to the same url in a rails integration test, with rspec

```
it 'does something' do

  # get '/something', {:status=>'any_other'}, @header ## <<<<< this line causes problem!

  get '/something', {:status=>'ok'}, @header
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
  lis = doc.css('#the_id')
  lis.size.should == 1
  lis[0].text.should include('anything')
end
```

If I make two requests to the same controller, the test seems to maintain the old response...

In the above example, if I uncomment that line, the test breaks beacause it maintains the result of the first 'query'

Is it a limitation of the test stack, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With plain old Rails test suite, functional tests are for single request and if you want to test flows you should use integration tests (you can reset the controller in functional tests).

Controller specs from rspec-rails inherit from Rails functional tests, so they have same limitation. You can use rspec with capybara or webrat (I recommend the former) for integration tests.

Also, recent versions of rspec-rails has "request specs" which "mix in behaivour of Rails integration tests": https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Answer (score 1):

rails integration tests should be written so that the on case tests the one single request - response cycle. we can check redirects. but if you have to do something like

get '/something', {:status=>'any_other'}, @header

get '/something', {:status=>'ok'}, @header

You should write two different cases for this.

Comment: If the designers of rspec don't want you to make a second request, the second request should raise an exception to stop you from doing so.  That way it comes through as a feature, not a bug.  Any idea why they didn't do that?

Comment: Yes, designers of rspec provided you with the feature. Its your requirement how you want to test it (as per the actual behaviour of the application).

Comment: I find this paradigm to be suboptimal because there are cases where I want to test idempotence of a request.

Answer (score 1):

Using Capybara instead of rspec is a better solution for (request) intergration tests.  It uses the same syntax as rspec and allow multiple requests in a single it block.  I use rspec for unit testing and capybara for integration testing.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your instance variables, or maybe the only necessary one. 
Let's pretend you use `@book` in your controller.

```
get '/something'
assert ...
controller.instance_variable_set(:@book, nil)
get '/something'
assert ...
```

If you are using `inherit_resources`

```
get '/something'
assert ...
controller.send(:set_resource_ivar, nil)
get '/something'
assert ...
```

Comment: This isn't good enough. RSpec keeps the old `params` lying around, and if you pass a new `params` to your second request, the `params` that your controller sees can be surprising at times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is that you are getting the same response, it is that you are actually sending the same request twice.

The following works for me when I want to make two requests in the same test:
`@request.delete_header 'RAW_POST_DATA'`