# Rails: multiple get requests in a single functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I would like to group some get requests in the same tests but I get erratic behavior. I have the following two tests:

```
test 'index for local seller (same site)' do
  seller = FactoryGirl.create :seller, business_site: @open_or.business_site
  get :index, nil, {user_id: seller.to_param }
  assert_select "table#order_requests tr##{@controller.view_context.dom_id @open_or}"
end
test 'index for local seller (different site)' do
  seller = FactoryGirl.create :seller_local
  get :index, nil, {user_id: seller.to_param }
  assert_select "table#order_requests tr##{@controller.view_context.dom_id @open_or}", false
end
```

which I would like to combine under one test but if I do so, the second assert will wrongly fail (Expected exactly 0 elements matching "table#order_requests tr#order_request_1000244799", found 1.). I don't really understand why? Something might not be reset properly for the second 'get' call. I looked for ways to 'reset' the request without success.

Related: [making two requests to the same controller in rails integrations specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850650/making-two-requests-to-the-same-controller-in-rails-integrations-specs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One important distinction I've noticed in functional tests (as opposed to integration) is that the state of a controller does not seem to be reset between requests, which can lead to unexpected results.  For example, consider this (contrived) controller:

```
class ThingyController < ApplicationController
  def one 
    @thingy = Thingy.first
    render :nothing => true
  end 

  def two 
    render :nothing => true
  end 
end
```

Action 'one' sets @thingy, while action 'two' doesn't. However, this functional test fails:

```
test "thingy should not exist in second request" do
  get :one
  assert_not_nil assigns(:thingy), "thingy should exist in get_one"
  get :two
  assert_nil assigns(:thingy), "thingy should be absent in get_two"
end
```

Presumably, it is because the @thingy from the first request remains as an instance variable in the controller for the duration of the test method.

While you can certainly make multiple get/put/etc calls within one test, I think they are not designed to test more than one action per test method.  Per the [Rails API TestCase docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html):

> Functional tests allow you to test a single controller action per test
>   method. This should not be confused with integration tests (see
>   ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest), which are more like “stories” that
>   can involve multiple controllers and multiple actions (i.e. multiple
>   different HTTP requests).

If you really wish to combine the two actions, perhaps an integration test would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you aren't showing the combined test, nor are you showing what failure so it's pretty much working in the dark but to combine those tests I might do something like

```
test 'index for seller (same site)' do
  first_seller = FactoryGirl.create :seller, business_site: @open_or.business_site
  get :index, nil, {user_id: first_seller.to_param }
  assert_select "table#order_requests tr##{@controller.view_context.dom_id @open_or}"
  second_seller = FactoryGirl.create :seller_local
  get :index, nil, {user_id: second_seller.to_param }
  assert_select "table#order_requests tr##{@controller.view_context.dom_id @open_or}", false
end
```

The above assumes that your separate tests pass and if so there is no reason that I can see why this would not work (but I'm not very good at seeing in the dark)

By the way, tests don't wrongly fail, there is always a reason for a failed test and it's normally a valid fail or an ill thought through test, either way it's a bug introduced by the programer not the tests fault at all!

**UPDATE** - have a look in the browser to see what is actually in the web page at the point the test fails using save_and_open_page as per railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

The difference between the combined test and separate tests is that the database gets cleared between each test so your first seller would still exist in the database in your combined test but won't exist in the second test when they are run as separate tests

Comment: This is exactly the test I mean by combining them. If I run this test, it will fail (Expected exactly 0 elements matching "table#order_requests tr#order_request_1000244799", found 1.) while keeping them separate both pass.

Comment: @gamov Paste your combined test that fails into your original question please.

Comment: But is it a valid fail? have you found a bug in your code? What do you see in your browser when you save_and_open_page as per railscast I linked to

Comment: It is a FUNCTIONAL test, not an INTEGRATION test, there is no capybara here.

Comment: Did you try clearing your database before the second test? It seems like your test is telling you that an order request exists when you are not expecting one. So why would that be?

Comment: @gamov Just thought I should clarify from your last comment. 2 requests in one test is an integration test not a functional test

Answer (score 0):

If you have many places where you differentiate between "same site" and "different site" behavior (or any other two-tiered behavior), it might make sense to add a helper method to test_helper.rb that simply adds the two tests for you:

```
def only_for_same_site_should(description, &action)
  class_eval do
    test "should #{description} if same site" do
      action.call(self, FactoryGirl.create :seller, true)
    end
    test "should NOT #{description} if different site" do
      action.call(self, FactoryGirl.create :seller_local, false)
    end
  end
end
```

And then use it in controller test classes like this:

```
only_for_same_site_should("have tag order_requests in index") do |test, seller, same_site|
  test.get :index, nil, {user_id: seller.to_param}
  assert_select "table#order_requests tr##{@controller.view_context.dom_id @open_or}", same_site
end
```